# Drupal views grids alternate number of columns per row template preprocessor

Tags: views, theming

im using views with the grid display option, but my interface requirement needs to alternate between 3 columns then 2 columns.

can anyone recommend and template hooks for the preprocessor to achieve this

Comment: The grid layout creates a table with a set number of columns in it, so I don't see a way to use it for your purpose.  However, you could use the unformatted style and then build a table yourself by overriding the appropriate Views template, filling in one row with 3 columns and the next row with 2, etc, and then looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619179/html-table-help-alternating-number-of-cells for some handy css and html to format it nicely.

Comment: Another option would be to use the unformatted style and use css floats and differing widths for each row to accomplish the approximate look and feel of the grid style.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this? I would really like to see an answer posted for this problem.